# Add 1 to every second number

Tags: python

How do I add 1 to every second number?
Example:

```
2323 -> 2424
1112 -> 1213
3912 -> 31013
```

That is what I have now:

```
def plus_to_every_second(integer):
    integer = str(integer)
    integer_new = ''
    for i in integer:
        if integer.find(i) % 2 != 0:
            integer_new += str(int(i) + 1)
        else:
            integer_new += i

    return integer_new
```

For some reason, it does not work.
But what is the actual solution?

Comment: Edit the question to explain "does not work". What happens, what should happen?

Comment: For one thing, `.find()` returns the _first_ occurrence of the target string.  So in your second example string "1112", `.find()` will return 0 for all three occurrences of "1".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `find`, that only finds the first occurrence, rather iterate the digits together with the position using `enumerate`:

IIUC, you could do:

```py
def add1(n):
    return int(''.join(str(int(d)+i%2) for i,d in enumerate(str(n))))

add1(2323)
# 2424

add1(1112)
# 1213

add1(3912)
# 31013
```

###### using a classical loop

```py
def add1(n):
    s = str(n)
    out = ''
    for i,d in enumerate(s):
        out += str(int(d)+i%2)
    return int(out)
```

Comment: Could you please code it several lines?

Comment: @Stamend sure but know that the comprehension is more pythonic and more efficient. You should try to understand it ;)

Answer (score 1):

This modified function should work:

```
def plus_to_every_second(integer):
    integer = str(integer)
    integer_new = ''
    for i in range(len(integer)):
      if i % 2 == 1:
        integer_new += str(int(integer[i]) + 1)
      else:
        integer_new += integer[i]
    return integer_new
```

First, as you did, we convert `integer` to a str and create a new variable, `integer_new` which holds an empty String.

However, in our for loop, we should iterate through `integer` so that we have access to the index.

If the index is odd (every second number), we then convert the character at that index to a number, add 1 to it, convert it back to a string, and then add it into `integer_new`.

If it's not at an odd index, then we just add the character into `integer_new`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't have the best performance, but you can do the following for a quick solution:

```
>>> number = 3912
>>> digit_lst = list(str(number))
>>> digit_lst
['3', '9', '1', '2']
>>> new_digit_lst = [n if i % 2 == 0 else str(int(n)+1) for i, n in enumerate(digit_lst)]
>>> new_digit_lst
['3', '10', '1', '3']
>>> new_number = int(''.join(new_digit_lst))
>>> new_number
31013
```